# Wordpress admin

Tags: wordpress, admin

Need to reset my admin details on wordpress, I have no idea what my admin username or password is; furthermore I don't have access to phpmyadmin either as I wasn't the one to set it up. would love some feedback!

Comment: Did you try resetting the password on the login screen?

Answer (score 1):

You can log in if you have access to the FTP where the site is hosted. If you have access, create a new php-file in the root directory (autologin.php for example), paste the following code and then visit your new file through the browser (link.com/autologin.php for example).

```
<?php

require_once('wp-load.php');

auto_login("admin"); //Change this to your username.

function auto_login($username) {
    $user = get_userdatabylogin($username);
    $user_id = $user->ID;
    wp_set_current_user($user_id, $user_login);
    wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id);
    do_action('wp_login', $user_login);
    wp_redirect(admin_url());
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the wordpress ftp?

If yes, you need to download the WP config file and now you have access to DB

Answer (score -1):

You can goto phpMyAdmin
Under tables goto wp_users
Then for whichever user you want to edit details click edit
replace password and change category to MD5